# Proving that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ diverges, where $a(n) = (1/2)^k$ for $2^{k-1} \le n < 2^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Let $a(n)=(1/2)^k$ when $2^{k-1} \le n < 2^k$ and $k$ is a natural number. How do you prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ diverges?

Comment: FAQ section --> directions to use LateX to write properly mathematics in this site.

Comment: In future questions, please try to make the title of your question more informative (I've done so for you now). E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Will do so in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compute the sum of $a_n$s for n in such a $k$-block. you have $2^{k-1}$ $a_n$s with the same value, hence it will be easy. then just conclude using Cauchy criterion

Comment: can you elaborate more on it please

Comment: what have you done so far? did you compute the sum of $a_n$'s in a block where they have the same value?

Comment: i know that the series is 1/2,1/4,1/4,1/8,1/8,1/8,1/8,1/16,1/16,1/16,1/16,1/16,1/16,1/16,1/16... and so on. So it can be seen that 2 different blocks can be selected such that the sum would be 1/2 but i am unable to write a proof

Comment: compute $\sum_{n=2^{k-1}}^{2^k - 1} a_n$ for a fixed k. As k grows this sum is 'farther' away, meaning it's composed of elements with big indexes. then check what Cauchy criterion states and use your computation to get a contradiction

Comment: Got it thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Define $b_1=a_1$ and $\displaystyle b_n=\sum_{t=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}{a_t}$ for $n\geq 2$ and note that $b_n=(2^n-2^{n-1}).\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. Hence we construct a block series from the series $\sum a_n$. So that the sum of series must be equal. Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2}}=\infty$.

Comment: can you explain further?